# select2 (remote data) throws exception because of typing to fast

Tags: jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 for loading remote data. I declared the minimumInputLength to 3 letters, so after that it will start searching.
Whenever I hit the fourth letter while typing fast I get an Javascript exception saying :

> Sorry. An error occured while communicating with the server. Please try again later.

How can I avoid this? I already changed the quietMillis (waitTimesMs) to lower or higher (does this even have something to do with it?).

Every help is appreciate.

My code is like:

`$(function () {
    $("#Search").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
            url: site,
            dataType: "json",
            quietMillis: waitTimeMs,
            data: function (params) {
                var page = (params.page || 1) - 1;
                return {
                    searchText: params.term,
                    pageCount: 10,
                    page: page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                var select2Data = $.map(data.Items, function (obj) {
                    obj.id = obj.ID;
                    obj.text = obj.Name;
                    return obj;
                });
                return {
                    results: select2Data,
                    pagination: { more: (data.PageNo * 10) < data.TotalCount }
                };
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works!
select2 changed "quietMillis" to "delay" so I could change quietMillis as big as I wanted and nothing changed at all...